# Descriptive statistics for categorical variables in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe of categorical variables in Python Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
cat_df = pd.DataFrame({'item':['bed',  'lamp', 'candle', 'chair', 'bed',  'candle', 'lamp'],
                  'location' :['home', 'home', 'home',   'home',  'home', 'home',   'home' ],
                  'status'   :['new',  'used', 'used',   'new',   'new',  'used',   'new' ]})

cat_df = cat_df.astype('category')
print(cat_df.dtypes)

cat_df.describe().transpose()
```

and I need an output that shows all the values of categorical variables plus the frequency and percentage

```
# item     bed    2 28.57
# item     lamp   2 28.57
# item     candle 2 28.57
# item     chair  1 14.28
# location home   7 100
# status   new    4 57.14
# status   used   3 42.85
```

The real dataset has a lot of variables so I need a scalable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for counts and then divide by `sum` to new column by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df1 = cat_df.melt(value_name='v', var_name='c')
df = df1.groupby(['c', 'v']).size().reset_index(name='count')
df['perc'] = df['count'].div(df.groupby('c')['count'].transform('sum')).mul(100)
print (df)
          c       v  count        perc
0      item     bed      2   28.571429
1      item  candle      2   28.571429
2      item   chair      1   14.285714
3      item    lamp      2   28.571429
4  location    home      7  100.000000
5    status     new      4   57.142857
6    status    used      3   42.857143
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I don't think the solution is straightforward enough. The real dataset has 7 categorical variables.

Comment: @Hamideh - hmmm, there is used `melt` for reshape, so it should working with `3,7 or 100 columns` correct (if need processing same way)

Comment: Can you do it in a way that preserves the order of values in categorical variables?

Comment: @Hamideh - You can try change `cat_df = cat_df.astype('category')` to `cat_df = cat_df.astype('category', ordered=True)`

Comment: I mean manual ordering. For example, If I want lamp to appear before other values: cat_df['item'] = cat_df['item'].cat.set_categories(['lamp', 'bed', 'candle', 'chair'])

Comment: @Hamideh - One idea should be convert each column to categories separately with pass `category` parameter with list of categories in expected order and `order=True` patameter

Comment: It works but in my real dataset, I have to set all the levels of categorical variables again (I did it before in the main dataset). For example, for yes/no variables I want yes to appear before no.

Comment: Do you need set order for all columns?

Comment: @Hamideh - Is possible create dictionary with custom order for all columns like `d = {'item': ['lamp', 'bed', 'candle', 'chair'],
     'location': ['home'], 
     'status': ['used','new']}`?